# In Flash Flash Revolution, how do I unlock the secret song "Final Fantasy Last Battle Festival"?

Tags: flash-flash-revolution

Question is straight forward, in the online flash game FlashFlashRevolution, there is a category listed as Secret, where you can unlock songs by getting higher and higher credit total. However, I currently have over 10,000 credits and that song still has not been unlocked. According the my levelrank page on the site, I have played the song once before. However, I have since spent and re-earned credits multiple times. Is there another way to songs in the Secret category or have I just not earned enough credits? I don't recall having made over 10,000 credits before, but my account was made 7 years ago and I just may not remember.

Comment: http://www.flashflashrevolution.com/vbz/showthread.php?t=116154 70k credits apparently.

Comment: @SimonL thanx, could you post that as an answer. Still curious as to went that 70k credit requirement was placed. I read elsewhere that someone had previously played that song and was now trying to earn 70k credits to play it again since it had been moved to secret.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable posting that as an answer because it feels like a link only answer. Also, since I don't play that game and couldn't find a direct response from the developer I can't guarantee that answer is correct. I also do not care about rep.

Comment: @SimonL I believe it is the correct answer none-the-less. You should post the answer and leave it open to edit if anyone has anything to add to it. But I think you pretty much answered the question.

Comment: For the sake of preserving the information, I've now made an answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 70,000 credits.

[Source](http://%20%20%20%09%20%09%20flashflashrevolution.com/vbz/showthread.php?t=116154) (As originally provided by SimonL)